# recvfrom returns invalid argument when *from* is passed

Tags: linux, sockets

I am currently writing a small UDP server program in linux. The UDP server will receive packets from two different peers and will perform different operations based on from which peer it received the packet. I am trying to determine the source from where I receive the packet. However, when `select` returns and `recvfrom` is called, it returns with an error of **Invalid Argument**. If I pass NULL as the second last arguments, recvfrom succeeds.

I have tried declaring fromAddr as `struct sockaddr_storage`, `struct sockaddr_in`, `struct sockaddr` without any success. Is their something wrong with this code? Is this the correct way to determine the source of the packet?

The code snippet follows.

```
`           
    /*TODO : update for TCP. use recv */
    if((pkInfo->rcvLen=recvfrom(psInfo->sockFd,
                                pkInfo->buffer,
                                MAX_PKTSZ,
                                0,
                               /* (struct sockaddr*)&fromAddr,*/
                               NULL,
                              &(addrLen)
                              )) < 0)
    {
       perror("RecvFrom failed\n");
    }
    else
    {
       /*Apply Filter */
    #if 0
       struct sockaddr_in* tmpAddr;
       tmpAddr = (struct sockaddr_in* )&fromAddr;
       printf("Received Msg From %s\n",inet_ntoa(tmpAddr->sin_addr));
    #endif
      printf("Packet Received of len = %d\n",pkInfo->rcvLen);
    }

`
```

Comment: Are you setting addrLen to the byte size of fromAddr before calling recvfrom()?  It needs to know how many bytes are available for it to fill in fromAddr with peer info.  On output, it will return the number of bytes filled in.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You must initialise `addrLen` to `sizeof fromAddr` before calling `recvfrom()` - it is an input/output parameter.  Using `struct sockaddr_storage` to declare `fromAddr` is correct.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem:

```
Invalid arguments 'Candidates are: int recvfrom(int, void *, unsigned int, int,
                   sockaddr *, unsigned int *) '
```

in same code:

```
recvfrom(sockFd, buffer, MAX_PKTSZ, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&fromAddr, &addrLen)
```

My mistake was that i used ordinary ***`int`*** type instead of ***`unsigned int`*** for *`addrLen`*:

```
unsigned int addrLen;
addrLen = sizeof(fromAddr);
```